# Mocking Cordova plugins in Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, unit-testing, jasmine

There is a piece of code I want to test in my controller:

```
$scope.fbLogin = function() {
  console.log('Start FB login');
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], FacebookServices.fbLoginSuccess, FacebookServices.fbLoginFailure);
};
```

The `facebookConnectPlugin` doesn't need to be injected to the controller. As long as I do `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4`, the `facebookConnectPlugin` is globally available.

In unit test, the `facebookConnectPlugin` is not available and since it doesn't need to be injected, the `$provide.value()` method doesn't do the magic any more.

Here is the error (complains on both source code and specs):

> ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
>           at Scope.$scope.fbLogin (/app/signup-and-login/controllers.js:9:6120)
>
> ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
>           at Object. (/app/signup-and-login/signup-specs.js:93:9)

Can someone shed some light on I can mock the plugin and provide it in the unit test environment?

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue. Solved this problem including a `globals.js` file on `karma.config.js` in files array. Then in globals.js I created a facebookConenctPlugin global. It ended with something like this:

`globals.js`

```
facebookConnectPlugin = {
  login: function(){...},
  logout: function(){...}
};
```

and in `karma.config.js`

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      'www/assets/lib/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      'node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      ...
      //// MOCK GLOBALS ///////////////////
      'test/mocks/globals.js',
      /////////////////////////////////////
      ...
    ],
    ...
};
```